# One to zero or one relationship with Code first c#

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm trying to learn to use Code First. On Picture 1 you can see the EER Model I want to become from my Code First application.

[image: PICTURE 1]

Now I have tried to get the same result from my application. Below you can see the EER Model I've managed to become from my app (with Reverse Engineering in MySQL Workbench).

[image: PICTURE 2]

As you can see I have a problem with creating a one to zero or one relationship between tables 'Properties' and 'Grounds'.

I have an abstract EntityBase class

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public abstract int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Also a GenericRepository class which inherits the EntityBase class

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : EntityBase
```

A MapDBContext class which inherits the DbContext class. Inside this class you can see that the OnModelCreating method is 'Override'. Inside of that method I have tried to configure the relationship between the 'Properties' and 'Grounds' tables.

```
public class MapDBContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Agreements> Agreements { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BuyersRenters> BuyersRenters { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Properties> Properties { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Grounds> Grounds { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Grounds>().HasOptional(s => s.Properties).WithRequired(lu => lu.Grounds);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public MapDBContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {

    }
}
```

Below are the two Code First classes of the 'Properties' and 'Grounds' tables (NOTE: Properties class is abstract):

```
[Table("eigendommen")]
public abstract class Properties : EntityBase
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("gemeente")]
    [Required]
    public string Town { get; set; }
    [Column("straat")]
    [Required]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Agreements> Agreements { get; set; }
    public virtual Grounds Grounds { get; set; }
}



[Table("gronden")]
public class Grounds : Properties
{
    [Key]
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("opp")]
    public double? Surface { get; set; }
    [Column("type")]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(TypeNames))]
    [Required]
    public TypeNames Types { get; set; }

    public virtual Properties Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Can somebody help me with what I am doing wrong? I've been searching for hours, tried with the 'required' attribute, with the '?' to make it nullable and with the 'ForeignKey' attribute. But all of these solutions give either errors or a similar table to the one I have now.

Comment: If you got a 1:1 relationship that maybe is a 1:0 sometimes, then you propably should heed rule 4 and 5: Remove that table. Strictly speaking you should always use the ZIP code as a primary key of the place name (because that what it is in reality). But practically every DB designer instinctively writes out both as part of the Adress.

Comment: This should help: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: this link may help you : http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**To define one to one and zero with code first c#**

if you want have one or zero Address for the student.

You can follow the code below

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() { }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public virtual StudentAddress StudentAddress { get; set; }

}

public class StudentAddress
{
    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentAddressId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

you must define **OnModelCreating** in the **DbContext** and then relation between student and studentaddress.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure the primary key for the StudentAddresses
    modelBuilder.Entity<StudentAddress>()
        .HasKey(t => t.StudentAddressId);

    // Map one-to-zero or one relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<StudentAddress>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.Student)
        .WithOptional(t => t.StudentAddress);

 }
```